# How can I convert str to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, encode

I have numbers of UTF-8 Bytes numbers
I want to convert these numbers to bytes to decode(utf-8)

```
uniA = 0xea
uniB = 0xb0
uniC = 0x80

ans = '\\x'+str("{0:x}".format(uniA))+'\\x'+str("{0:x}".format(uniB))+'\\x'+str("{0:x}".format(uniC))+''
print(ans) 
>>> \xea\xb0\x80
```

I want to get `ans.decode('utf-8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert *int objects* to the corresponding `bytes` object, which is directly supported by `bytes`, by providing it an iterable of `int` objects, e.g. a list:

```
>>> uniA = 0xea
>>> uniB = 0xb0
>>> uniC = 0x80
>>> type(uniA)
<class 'int'>
>>> bytes([uniA, uniB, uniC]).decode('utf8')
'가'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will get a byte string that you can decode:

```
ans = bytes([uniA,uniB,uniC])
print(ans.decode('utf8'))
```